# using ffmpeg to convert gif to mp4 , output doesn't play on android

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, mp4

I just use the following command to convert a gif file to mp4 but the resulting mp4 file doesn't play in android default video player .
what did I wrong ?
is there any aditional steps should I take to produce android playable mp4 files ?

```
$ ffmpeg -f gif -i infile.gif outfile.mp4
```

my test gif file : [Test Gif File](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/images_blogs/design/2013/09/tumblr_inline_mjx5ioXh8l1qz4rgp.gif)
My desktop played the output.mp4 very well using VLC Media Player and also MX Player on my android device played the video file without any error.

Comment: I think you could use ffmpeg -f gif -i file.gif -c:v libx264 outfile.mp4

Comment: Pl. refer to the below url  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40638/how-to-do-i-convert-an-animated-gif-to-an-mp4-or-mv4-on-the-command-line                                                                      Another way to convert GIF animation to video:

ffmpeg -i your_gif.gif -c:v libvpx -crf 12 -b:v 500K output.mp4
-crf values can go from 4 to 63. Lower values mean better quality. -b:v is the maximum allowed bitrate. Higher means better quality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i file.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" out.mp4
```

Comment: Could you explain what this does?

Comment: @Tom the default codec is `yuv444p` which apparently can't be played in some mobile browsers (read: Mobile Safari and probably older mobile browsers in general). I googled the cryptic scale argument and found this: https://github.com/manateelazycat/deepin-screen-recorder/commit/a49612faed28fc70a98aa117839cc67d96b99761

Comment: Additionally, Safari I think only plays the file if both width and height are divisible by 2 which is what the cryptic `-vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"` line "fixes" for you.