# How to convert a GIF to optimized mp4 video using FFMPEG on android?

Tags: android, c, video, ffmpeg, gif

I successfully integrated FFMPEG as a library on android and I am using JNI to communicate my JAVA classes with C and C++ classes.

**Background and my question**
A chat app where GIFs can be sent, the issue is that one GIF could weigh up to 2MB, after a lot of research I found that the best solution is converting those gifs to mp4 (Something that Facebook messenger, whatsapp and telegram do).

My question is, how can I convert a gif to mp4 in order to reduce its size, using ffmpeg (not in command line, in android)  as Telegram mentions [here](https://telegram.org/blog/gif-revolution) ?

**What I have attempted**

- Understanding and implementing the [gifvdeo.cpp](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/jni/gifvideo.cpp) from Telegram (it was extremely complicated and I could not understand it fully)
- Converting the gif to frames of bitmaps, and compressing each bitmap and then converting those bitmaps to mp4 (I was not able to pass the bitmap object to C through JNI because of " Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x31f in tid 26952" which is another question)

**Research I have done**

- [using ffmpeg to convert gif to mp4 , output doesn't play on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781238/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-gif-to-mp4-output-doesnt-play-on-android)
- [How to convert GIF to Mp4 is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233394/how-to-convert-gif-to-mp4-is-it-possible)
- [Convert GIF to Video in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481244/convert-gif-to-video-in-android)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40638/how-to-do-i-convert-an-animated-gif-to-an-mp4-or-mv4-on-the-command-line

the problem with above questions is that they use command line FFMPEG which is not what I am doing, I am using JNI and direct access to c classes of mentioned library.

Comment: "*using ffmpeg (not in command line*" look up what the ffmpeg command line tool actually does (by peeking into its source) when converting a .gif to a .mp4 and wrap this into a function you then call from java.

Comment: @alk apologies for the late reply, well yes, I have checked what the ffmpeg.c does, its main method receives 2 parameters, an array (parameters of the command) and its length.
That's not what I want to do as it's very slow on an android device.